# pdf download file does not respond to CSS

Tags: html, css, pdf, mpdf

I have table headers that I styled with writing-mode: vertical-lr. It displays perfectly on screen.

[image: vertical header table]

I used the same CSS to style the PDF file. However, the headers were not displayed vertically. In fact, it doesn't respond to many CSS styling.

[image: No style table]

What do I do to make the PDF file display like the one onscreen upon download?

```html
<table>
<thead>
                    <tr>
                         <th style="border: 1px solid black; font-size:11px;width:120px;text-align:center;font-weight: bolder;color: black;vertical-align: bottom;">
                                                    SUBJECTS
                                                </th>
                                               <th style="border: 1px solid black; font-size:11px;width:50px;font-weight: bolder;color: black;writing-mode: vertical-lr;transform: rotate(180deg);vertical-align: middle;">
                                                    CA1 10%
                                                </th>
                                               <th style="border: 1px solid black; font-size:11px;width:50px;font-weight: bolder;color: black;writing-mode: vertical-lr;transform: rotate(180deg);vertical-align: middle;">
                                                    CA2 10%
                                                </th>
                                               <th style="border: 1px solid black; font-size:11px;width:50px;font-weight: bolder;color: black;writing-mode: vertical-lr;transform: rotate(180deg);vertical-align: middle;">
                                                    CA3 10%
                                                </th>
                                                <th style="border: 1px solid black; font-size:11px;width:50px;font-weight: bolder;color: black;writing-mode: vertical-lr;transform: rotate(180deg);vertical-align: middle;">
                                                    CA4 10%
                                                </th>
                                                <th style="border: 1px solid black; font-size:11px;width:50px;font-weight: bolder;color: black;writing-mode: vertical-lr;transform: rotate(180deg);vertical-align: middle;">
                                                    CA5 10%
                                                </th>
                                                <th style="border: 1px solid black; font-size:11px;width:50px;;font-weight: bolder;color: black;writing-mode: vertical-lr;transform: rotate(180deg);vertical-align: middle;">
                                                    CA6 10%
                                                </th>
                                                <th style="border: 1px solid black; font-size:11px;width:50px;font-weight: bolder;color: black;writing-mode: vertical-lr;transform: rotate(180deg);vertical-align: middle;">
                                                    CA TOTAL 60%
                                                </th>
                                                <th style="border: 1px solid black; font-size:11px;width:50px;font-weight: bolder;color: black;writing-mode: vertical-lr;transform: rotate(180deg);vertical-align: middle;">
                                                    EXAM 40%
                                                </th>
                                                <th style="border: 1px solid black; font-size:11px;width:50px;font-weight: bolder;color: black;writing-mode: vertical-lr;transform: rotate(180deg);vertical-align: middle;">
                                                    TOTAL 100%
                                                </th>
                                                <th style="border: 1px solid black; font-size:11px;width:50px;font-weight: bolder;color: black;writing-mode: vertical-lr;transform: rotate(180deg);vertical-align: middle;">
                                                    GRADE
                                                </th>
                                               <th style="border: 1px solid black; font-size:11px;width:50px;font-weight: bolder;color: black;writing-mode: vertical-lr;transform: rotate(180deg);vertical-align: middle;">
                                                    HIGHEST IN CLASS
                                                </th>
                                                <th style="border: 1px solid black; font-size:11px;width:50px;font-weight: bolder;color: black;writing-mode: vertical-lr;transform: rotate(180deg);vertical-align: middle;">
                                                    LOWEST IN CLASS
                                                </th>
                                                <th style="border: 1px solid black; font-size:11px;width:50px;font-weight: bolder;color: black;writing-mode: vertical-lr;transform: rotate(180deg);vertical-align: middle;">
                                                    POSITION
                                                </th>
                                                <th style="border: 1px solid black; font-size:11px;width:50px;font-weight: bolder;color: black;writing-mode: vertical-lr;transform: rotate(180deg);vertical-align: middle;">
                                                    REMARK
                                                </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                </table>
```

Comment: What do you mean `I used the same CSS to style the PDF file`? What are you using to generate the PDF? Are you talking about print styles? What browser?

Comment: @Dominik — The question is tagged [tag:mpdf]

Comment: It is now indeed.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure it out using this solution https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/issues/357

I applied the text-rotate attribute only to the tr tag for the headers.

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr text-rotate="90">
<th><p>Element type 1A</p><p>Second line</p><th><p>Element type longer 2A</p></th>
<th>Element type 3B</th>
<th>Element type 4B</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

The texts in the headers were all rotated.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for mpdf includes a section on [supported CSS](https://mpdf.github.io/css-stylesheets/supported-css.html). The `writing-mode` property you depend on is not there. It also doesn't support `rotate()` which you might otherwise have tried to use for this.

I don't think you can solve this without changing to a different PDF generating library.